# replace exact word while ignoring punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I would like to know how to replace an exact word BUT with the exception of ignoring punctuation

I've see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) which is nice but fails on the edges for me.

Here is an example to what I would like to replace:

```
"hi my name is John, and I am 30 yrs old."
```

to

```
"to hi my name is ted, and I am 30 yrs old."
```

Thanks

Comment: Dd you try anything yourself?

Comment: Sure, but I am not too good at regex

Comment: I'm confused. Does "ignoring punctuation" mean "removing punctuation from the end product", or "not doing anything special with existing punctuation, leaving it where it is"? If it's the former, why does your output still have punctuation? And if it's the latter, why did you mention it at all, and why did you link to a question about removing punctuation?

Comment: Yeah, no idea why punctuation is even being mentioned here. Do you just want to replace "John" with "Ted" in a string?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "hi my name is John, and I am 30 yrs old."
>>> new_s = s.replace("John", "Ted")
>>> new_s
'hi my name is Ted, and I am 30 yrs old.'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\bJohn\b
```

This should do it for you.Replace by `ted`.

Comment: This is what the link I added suggested, try it, it doesn't word

Comment: @OferHelman apply like `re.sub(r"\bJohn\b","ted",test_str)` dont forget the `r`